# Regex to capture series of numbers with specific bins

Tags: java, regex

We used the regex below to capture existing card numbers who fall into specific bins and use it for some analysis.

For card bins starting with 5

```
^(?:5[1-5][0-9]{2}|222[1-9]|22[3-9][0-9]|2[3-6][0-9]{2}|27[01][0-9]|2720)[0-9]{12}$
```

For card bins starting with 4

```
^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?$
```

A new set of card bins (see below) needs to be captured but the regex shown above is not able to capture it.
The input is a full card number with 16 Digits and the first 6 numbers is analyzed and checked if it falls into one of the regex just specified.

Unfortunately none of us are really good with regex so I sought some help on how we can modify the regex logic to capture the bins below. Thanks

```
437544
550156
539628
458209
458208
```

Comment: maybe [**`^[45][0-6][01246-9]\d[0-579][0-46-9]`**](https://regex101.com/r/gcbrYK/2)

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand the question here. Are you trying to combine your regular expressions or have your regular expressions also work for 6-digit numbers beginning with 4 or 5?

Comment: `^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?$` will match either a 13-digit number starting with 4 or a 16-digit number starting with 4.  Your list is only of 6-digit numbers, unless I'm misunderstanding your question.  To match those numbers, you'd use `^[45][0-9]{5}$`.

Comment: Note that your pattern "For card bins starting with 5" appears to match several patterns that start with 2.

Comment: The question is unclear, but if you want something that will only match CC numbers beginning with any value in the given bin then you can try this: `^4(0(2016|632[79])|1(4758|7997)|20230|3754[48]|40413|5(7(377|852)|82(0[89]|1[0-2])|9227)|69679)|5(2(1570|8243|9909)|39(179|628)|50(043|156))[0-9]{10}$`. I wrote this manually by treating the bin values as a tree. However, regular expressions are not wonderfully suited for matching values from a bin like this. It would likely be more computationally efficient (and readable) to do a simple string comparison, instead.

Comment: You might also consider using a [trie](https://www.toptal.com/java/the-trie-a-neglected-data-structure) for large data sets. Searching that data structure is essentially the same as what is done here but without the additional overhead of the regular expression engine and the difficulty associated with managing patterns for the bins.

Comment: @MikeHill thanks for your suggestion did you combine two regex into one expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the segment to find those numbers, and *only* those.
Obtained via this tool:
http://www.regexformat.com/version7_files/Rx5_ScrnSht01.jpg

*Note this is a ternary tree turned into a regex `trie` making it the fastest

regex on the planet for this stuff.*

Also, it might actually be faster to take *ALL* valid 16 digit bin numbers,
dump it into this utility and generate a regex *trie*.
This is the fastest method on the planet. No other way is faster.
The utility takes unlimited number of strings.
Examples -
*[175,000 word dictionary](http://www.regexformat.com/Dnl/_Samples/_Ternary_Tool%20(Dictionary)/___txt/_ASCII_175,000_word_Mix_A-Z_Multi_Lined.txt)*
*[100,000 domains](http://www.regexformat.com/Dnl/_Samples/_Ternary_Tool%20(Dictionary)/___txt/_100_000_Domain_Names.txt)*

`(?:4(?:0(?:2016|632[79])|1(?:4758|7997)|20230|3754[48]|40413|5(?:7(?:377|852)|82(?:0[89]|1[012])|9227)|69679)|5(?:2(?:1570|8243|9909)|39(?:179|628)|50(?:043|156)))`

All you have to do is put it into an assertion at the start of your regex:
`^(?= <this regex> ) <existing regex> $`

You could actually *join* your two regex into one, giving each a capture
group as a flag as to what bin it qualifies for.

`^(?= <this regex> ) (?: (<existing regex for 4>) | (<existing regex for 5>) )$`

Formatted

```
 (?:
      4
      (?:
           0
           (?: 2016 | 632 [79] )
        |  1
           (?: 4758 | 7997 )
        |  20230
        |  3754 [48] 
        |  40413
        |  5
           (?:
                7
                (?: 377 | 852 )
             |  82
                (?: 0 [89] | 1 [012] )
             |  9227
           )
        |  69679
      )
   |  5
      (?:
           2
           (?: 1570 | 8243 | 9909 )
        |  39
           (?: 179 | 628 )
        |  50
           (?: 043 | 156 )
      )
 )
```

---

***[Benchmark](http://www.regexformat.com/scrn7/s7_b1.jpg) Samples***

The first benchmark's input sample is 27 entries.
The second benchmark's input sample is the 27 entries repeated to get 1,000,000 entries.

```
437544
437548
458212
469679
457377
457852
469679
458212
420230
402016
406327
406329
528243
521570
529909
539179
550043
550156
539628
458209
458208
417997
459227
458210
440413
458211
414758
```

***Benchmark - 1***

```
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   38  /  38     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   27
Elapsed Time:    1.008 s,   1008.38 ms,   1008383 µs
```

38,000 iterations per 1.008 second  *  27 matches per iteration = 1,017,857 matches per second

***Benchmark - 2***

```
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   1  /  1     ( x 1 )
Matches found per iteration:   1000000
Elapsed Time:    0.96 s,   959.45 ms,   959451 µs
```

1 iterations per 0.96 second  *  1,000,000 matches per iteration = 1,026,000 matches per second

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. The sol'n you provided combines two regex as far as I understood. However we need to make the distinction as the card number bin belongs to 5 or 4.

Comment: @dimas - You don't need to chop up this regex to use 4 or 5 seperately, but you could. Like I said there is no overhead difference, it's just a 4 or 5. Put it into an assertion like said and use with either regex.